# Summation of values in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am new to programming and this is my first time using freemarker. I was wondering if there is a way to get the summation of the values.

My current code is this:

```
<td>Total Boxes:</td>
<td><#if invtransfer?has_content>
    <#if record.custbody_hdr_sort_by == "Item Category">
    <#list invtransfer?sort_by("x.item.class?split(':')[0]?trim") as x>
    <#assign currCategory>${x.item.class?split(':')[0]?trim}</#assign>
    <#if currCategory == cat>
    <#if x.unit == "PIECE">
    ${(x.item.unitstype?split("/")[0]?trim?number) * (x.quantityuom?replace("-", "")?number)}
    <#elseif x.unit == "BOX">
    ${x.quantityuom?replace("-", "")}
    <#elseif x.unit == "PALLET">
    ${(x.item.unitstype?split("/")[1]?trim?number) * (x.quantityuom?replace("-", "")?number)}
    </#if>
    </#if>
    </#list>
    </#if>
    </#if>
 </td>
```

and my current output is this:

```
Total Boxes: 3 4 5
```

How do I add them all to get `Total Boxes: 12`?

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: You can use something like `<#assign sumVar = sumVar + value>`

Comment: Or a bit more succinctly: `<#assign sumVar += value>`

Comment: By the way `<#assign currCategory>${x.item.class?split(':')[0]?trim}</#assign>` should be written as `<#assign currCategory = x.item.class?split(':')[0]?trim>`. That becomes important if the result is not a string, and you need to keep the type.

Comment: Also instead of `?split(':')[0]` you can use `?keep_before(':')`, which works even if there's no `:` in the value.

Comment: Also that `?sort_by` will not work, because you can only give column names there, not complex expressions.